# div with absolutely positioned <span> overwrites next <div>

Tags: css, position, absolute, overwrite

I have a series of divs with two spans each.  Second span is absolutely positioned for column alignment.  Problem is that if the text in the second span is long enough to force a second line, that line overwrites the next div in the sequence.

You can see it at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jalexander_ca/swuZ3/1/)

Here's some code:

```
<code><div id='container'>
<div class='solodiv'><span class='cvyear' >2011</span><span class='cvtext'>
    <em>Item 1</em>Text that's long enough to force a second line which overwrites the next line</span></div>
<div class='solodiv'><span class='cvyear'>2010</span><span class='cvtext'>
    <em>Item 2</em> Item 2 text, shorter</span></div>
<div class='solodiv'><span class='cvyear'>2008 - 2009</span><span class='cvtext'>
    <em>Item 3</em> Item 3 text, one line only</span></div>
```

And the .css:

```
#container {
font-family:sans-serif;
position:absolute;
left:10px;
top:10px;
width:600px,
}
.cvtext {
position:absolute;
left:120px;
width:480px;
}
```

I know there are many many topics similar to this, but I can't find the solution, other than to use tables.  Do I have to?

Comment: What's the problem with using a table? It looks like you're displaying tabular data.

Comment: Thanks Russell.  No problem, just thought I should be able to do it without tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CSS to the following:

```
#container {
font-family:sans-serif;
position:absolute;
left:10px;
top:10px;
width:600px;
}

.cvtext {
float: left;
width: 480px;
}

.cvyear {
float: left;
width: 120px;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/swuZ3/3/) is a modified Fiddle that demonstrates this working.

Comment: This works too, however, I'm slightly more in favor of the `display: table-cell` method because should the text be longer than '2011' on the left –- which doesn't appear to be the case here -- the floats will start messing up (example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swuZ3/5/)).

Comment: This is easily fixed by inserting a div with a style of `clear:both;` after the `solodiv` - http://jsfiddle.net/swuZ3/6/

Your method is equally valid - just a different implementation that solves the same problem :) I prefer to use floats, as `display: table-cell;` has compatibility issues in IE7.

Comment: Why the extra markup when you don't need it? Regardless, I agree. Either solution should work for the OP and both equally valid :)

Comment: Because table-cell doesn't work in IE7. It's a bit of extra markup, but it's backwards compatible. That said, it's about time IE7 died a fiery death.

Comment: Lol. I forgot about IE7. I looked around and it's down to about 4% global usage and the same for the US. Here's to the death of IE7!

Comment: Thanks Josh and Tracy for exactly what I was looking for.  - What's an OP?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this isn't too hasty of an answer that I may be missing something, but it seems to me that you could set `.cvyear` and `.cvtext` to `display: table-cell` without using an actual table. This will treat your spans like table-cells.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swuZ3/4/).

And the CSS:

```
#container {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 600px,
}

.cvyear {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 120px;
}

.cvtext {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 480px;
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes it is, both excellent answers.  Thank you very much!  I don't know how to vote for both....